# Deregistering Object from an Object Manager upon Garbage Collection (Java)

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection

In my game, I have a `Population` class that contains a set of citizens. Each population registers itself with a `PopulationManager` upon instantiation. The `PopulationManager` contains a reference to all `Population` objects in the game; it is used for analysis of populations and quickly retrieving populations.

Many structures within my game may contain a `Population`. Ex. a `Town` contains a `Population`. When a town is destroyed, I want the population object to cease to exist as well. However, even if I destroy a town, its `Population` object remains, since there is a reference to it in the `PopulationMananger`.

Is there a way of removing the reference to a `Population` object in the `PopulationManager` when its `Town` is destroyed without explicitly calling some sort of *deregister(Population)* method in the `PopulationManager`? Or will I be forced to remove the reference manually each time a town is destroyed?

Comment: Look up the Observer pattern.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you. Upon initial google search, this looks to be exactly what I need.

Comment: @mario_sunny Not really :) It's just a fancy way of calling `deregister` - the very thing you wanted to avoid.
What you really need is `java.lang.ref.WeakReference`.

Comment: @Dima Thank you I will look this up as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using a weakHashMap with the key as the town object and the value as the population object.

The WeakHashMap is just anotehr Map which keeps tracks of the weak references i.e, in your case, if at all the town object is assigned null, the weakHashMap will ensure that on garbage collection, the entry corresponding to that town object gets deleted.

This way, you have to care about only the town object, the rest will doen by the WeakHashMap itself